# Как при помощи js с генерировать двухуровневое меню?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно в хедере сайта динамически при помощи js сгенерировать двухуровневое меню типа `ul > li > a` и динамически добавить заголовок для меню - кнопка "Меню".

Написал вот такое (код HTML):

```
    <body>
     <header>
     </header>
     <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure error molestiae quod asperiores explicabo praesentium et ex a blanditiis ut ad assumenda cum quibusdam recusandae adipisci libero alias architecto earum.</p>
    </section>
  </body>
```

код CSS

```
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0; }
    header, section {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 1170px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: auto;
      background-color: #f0ddc4; }
    section {
      background-color: #c2c2c2; }
    ul.menu {
      list-style-type: none;}
    ul.menu li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 10px;}
    ul.menu li a{
      color: #000;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 30px;}
    ul.menu li a:hover{
      color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #fff;}
```

ну и собственно начал писать код JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $( "header" ).append( "<ul class='menu'><li><a>'item1'</a></li></ul>");
    });
```

Такой вопрос: это код добавляет одну li в меню, а если необходимо больше то как это прописать? И как правильно оформить этот js код?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вам пример небольшой. В menu храним структуру меню и при готовности DOM обрабатываем эту структуру генерируя html код ...

```
var menu = [
        {
        name: 'Menu 1',
        submenu: [
            {
                name: 'Submenu 1',
                href: 'http://someurl.ru',
                id: 'submenu1'
            },
            {
                name: 'Submenu 2',
                href: 'http://someur2.ru',
                id: 'submenu2'
            },
            {
                name: 'Submenu 3',
                href: 'http://someur3.ru',
                id: 'submenu3'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Menu 2',
        submenu: [
            {
                name: 'Submenu 2 1',
                href: 'wwww.ccc.ru',
                id: 'submenu21'
            },
            {
                name: 'Submenu 2 2',
                href: 'wwww.vcxcvxv.ru',
                id: 'submenu22'
            }
        ]        
    }
];


$(document).ready(function(){

    var html = '';
    html += '<ul class="menu">';

    $.each(menu, function(key,value) {

        html += '<li><a>'+value.name+'</a>';
        html += '<ul class="submenu">';

        $.each(value.submenu, function(skey,svalue) {
            html += '<li><a id="'+svalue.id+'" href="'+svalue.href+'">'+svalue.name+'</a></li>';
        });

        html += '</ul></li>';
    });

    html += '</ul>';
    $( "header" ).append(html);
});
```

Comment: $('header').append(.button); могу ли я этой командой добавить кнопку в меню?

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю что подразумевается под .button, но уверен, что нет.

Comment: кнопка меню, которая будет прятать при клике само меню при ресайзе окна браузера

Answer (score 0):

Начните с заголовка и кнопки меню. Готовыхх решений для самого меню предостаточно в сети.

Comment: в сети готовые меню сделанные на css и js, но речь идет не о том. Мне надо создать меню на чистом js, точнее с генерировать.

Comment: Ну например ... Запихивайте данные для меню `{'Main': ['submain1','submain2'] ,'Menu2': ['Menu21','Menu22']}`. Разбираете с помощью  2 циклов, в первом генерируете первый уровень, во втором  -  второй.